# containsAll return False when comparing two ArrayList of object

Tags: java, arraylist

I have two ArrayList as :

ArrayOne

```
ClassPojo [Name ="XXX", FilterID = 4]
ClassPojo [Name = "ZZZ", FilterID = 5]
```

ArrayTwo

```
ClassPojo [Name = "XXX", FilterID = 4]
```

but when try to use:

```
 Arrays.asList(ArrayOne).contains(ArrayTwo )
```

or

```
ArrayOne().containsAll(ArrayTwo)
```

it returns false,
i know the comparing is based on Refrences not Values equlaty
but how i can do it by values 
note that: i want to use conatinsAll , so if the content of arrayTwo is found in some part of ArrayOne return true .

Comment: you are using very different method signatures.
contains: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains-java.lang.Object- Is for a ClassPojo element, not the List.

containsAll -https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#containsAll-java.util.Collection -  does take a list, but as mentioned in lots of comments below you need to implement equals method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order for the `contains` or `containsall` to work you need to override the [equals()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) function in your class `ClassPojo`.

It could look like this :

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj){
    if (obj.Name.equals(this.Name) && obj.FilterID == this.FilterID)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

(written using phone so be careful with just copy paste)

Comment: method does not override method from its superclass

Comment: cannot reslove method equals (equals(this.FilterID)) for int

Comment: Check, indeed, updated code.

Answer (score 7):

> i know the comparing is based on references not Values equality

No, it is based on value equality. You need to override `equals()` to properly compare 2 objects of your `ClassPojo`

Comment: so why it return false then?

Comment: It uses `equals()` of `Object` inherited. which says `false`

Comment: so why it return false , there is two same values with filterID=4

Comment: debug in your IDE. put a breakpoint in `java.lang.Object#equals()`

Comment: i'm don't use equals() , i'm using ArrayOne().containsAll(ArrayTwo) , and i have tested it and it returns false

Comment: it gets called internally.